# How do I visualise the p95/p99 for a Cloudwatch data source in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

We're using the Cloudwatch data source in Grafana. I can see in Cloudwatch we can dynamically type in a pXX value of p95 for instance:

[image: Cloudwatch Option to pick p95]

But in Grafana I can only see the following: Average, Maximum, Minimum, SampleCount

[image: Grafana Statistics List]

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways to do it:

## Type it in

You can type in `p95` into the Statistic box (the dropdown won't show you the option, but you can type it in).

Note you also can't delete the text elements - typing it in will overwrite it.

[image: Typing in p95 into the Statistic box]

## Making a variable

The other way I found how to do this is to add a custom variable:

[image: Custom variables settings]

I included the Maximum,Minimum,Average and then I added p95 and p90 (but you can add any p value).

You can also add any of the other statistics here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Statistics-definitions.html

Then in the Grafana dashboard set the variable `statistic` (or whatever you decide to call it) to your new variable and your graph will now show p95.

[image: Grafana showing choosing the custom variable for Cloudwatch]

Comment: Actually, you can write custom value into statistic field. So you can write p95 there and you don't need dashboard variable for that.

Comment: Ah! Thank you @JanGaraj - I didn't realise that. I'll update the answer.